# sqlite usage and purpose

Tags: sqlite, pysqlite

Could someone provide an examples about why sqlite db is needed and for which purposes,
especially if it can be used by security application?

Answer (score 2):

There's a document on their homepage: [Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a very small database system. It provides database functionality to things that typically weren't treated as databases, such as application settings.

Ruby on Rails uses SQLite (and certainly Django) for testing purposes before web applications are deployed in larger environments.

The iPhone uses SQLite to store application settings.

A SQLite database is stored on a file system as a single file. Moving a SQLite database is as simple as "mv" or drag & drop.